# Showing components on checkbox click in react

Tags: html, css, reactjs, checkbox

Hello i'm new to react and I have a problem regarding checkbox click handling in react. I want to show a div when a check box is checked and remove the div if the checkbox is unchecked.

The way I have done this only shows the div when the checkbox is clicked but it does not remove the div when it is unchecked. How can I do this in react?

```
class QuestionOverlay extends Component {

    constructor() {

        super();

        this.showComments = this.showComments.bind(this);

        this.state = {

            showComponent: false,
        };

    }


    showComments = (e) => {

        this.setState({

            showComponent: true,

        });

    }

    render() {

           return (

                <div className="add_checkbox">

                   <span>Enable Comments</span>
                   <input className="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="enable_comment" onClick={this.showComments} value="enable_comment"/>

                </div>



                {this.state.showComponent ? <div  className="comments_preview_sample"></div> : null}

        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason is you are always setting the value of `showComponent=true`, you need to reset the state variable when the checkbox is unchecked, Use this:

```
showComments(e){

    this.setState({
        showComponent: e.target.checked,
    });

}
```

Check the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mrqutgbz/

Few things you need to change:

*You are `returning` 2 element from `render`, one `div` and one more `div` from conditional `rendering`. We can't return more than one `html` element from `render`, so put the conditional rendering in the main `div`.

*You are `binding` the `showComments` method twice, one in `constructor` and another by using `arrow`, remove the `arrow`, that is not required.

*Div that you are `rendering` on condition is empty, put some content in that.

Comment: glad, to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `onClick` listener to `onChange`. Then, rename `showComments` to `toggleComments` and implement it like so:

```
toggleComments(e) {
  this.setState({ showComponent: e.target.checked });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are several syntax error in your code:

1. Function defined in a `class` can't use `=` way.
2. React render function need a root container like `div` tag.

```js
const { Component } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

class QuestionOverlay extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   showComponent: false
  }
  this.showComments = this.showComments.bind(this);
 }

 showComments() {
  this.setState({
   showComponent: !this.state.showComponent
  });
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <div>
    <div className="add_checkbox">
     Enable Comments <br/>
     <input type="checkbox" onClick={this.showComments} />
    </div>
    {this.state.showComponent ? <div className="comments_preview_sample">comments</div> : null}
   </div>
  );
 }
}

render(
 <QuestionOverlay />,
 document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: It has a root container.i just did not include it here as it's not necessary for my question